# Create sequence pattern in R

Tags: r, transactions

I have this dataframe.

```
 id Trans_Date  Item
100  11/3/2013     A
100  11/3/2013     B
100  18/3/2013     A
101  17/3/2013     C
101  21/3/2013     B
103  12/3/2013     D
103  14/3/2013     A
```

from this dataframe

i need to get below sequencial dataset.

```
 id  Item
100 A,B,A
101   C,B
103   D,A
```

How to do it in R? Using `arulesSequence` package or other method?

Please help me friends.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group by `id` then use `toString()`.  Here is a base R solution:

```
aggregate(Item ~ id, df, toString)
#    id    Item
# 1 100 A, B, A
# 2 101    C, B
# 3 103    D, A
```

Or with *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, toString(Item), by = id]
    id      V1
# 1: 100 A, B, A
# 2: 101    C, B
# 3: 103    D, A
```

Or if you prefer *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
summarise(group_by(df, id), Item = toString(Item))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#      id    Item
#   (int)   (chr)
# 1   100 A, B, A
# 2   101    C, B
# 3   103    D, A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help..i got it.Richard Scriven i saw ur profile. u r expert in R. please suggest any R books that include real life example case stadies

Comment: @Peter - Happy to help.  If this (or any) answer worked for you, you can click the grey check-mark to accept it.

Comment: I don't think I'm an expert, but thanks!  I like the Chapman & Hall *R Series* books